# send email after `make` completes, even with failure

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a Makefile that is organizing several steps of analysis that have to be run in a particular order. The analysis takes quite a while (a day or two) and I'd like to receive some email notifications when `make` completes. Is there a good way to have make automatically send an email at the end of the process so I can be alerted when it completes, *especially* when there is a failure with one of the steps?

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
# Makefile
all: results1.dat results2.dat results3.dat
    python send_email_when_done.py

results1.dat: long_running_program1.py
    python $< > $@ # this takes ~12 hours

results2.dat: long_running_program1.py results1.dat
    python $^ > $@ # this takes ~2 hours 

results2.dat: long_running_program1.py results2.dat
    python $^ > $@ # this takes ~30 hours
```

where the `send_email_when_done.py` script sends email notifications when the process has completed. But this only works if the entire process has run from start to finish without any errors. Any suggestions for a good way to do this?

+1 for suggestions that can accomplish this within the `Makefile`. I'm already running `make` in a separate session using `setsid make > make.out 2>&1`.

Comment: Maybe an idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634178/can-a-makefile-target-invoke-commands-even-if-a-prerequisite-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply make the email sending as a separated target:

```
report: long_running_program1.py
    python $< > $@ # this takes ~12 hours

sendmail:
    python send_email_when_done.py
```

And you call it:

```
make report sendmail
or
make report ; make sendmail
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me make it more general so that it can send email for 100's of other such `make`. Use alias and add it in `bashrc`, here [sagarsakre.blogspot.in](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.in/2012/11/bashrc.html) is how i tried to use the `alias` command `makes` (`make` and `s`end report). The added advantage would be u would get all the `verbose` printed regardless of worrying about rule and dependency. You can use it for all builds without really changing the `makefile`.

note: i used mailx, You can read [this](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.in/2012/09/sending-emails-from-terminal-using.html) to setup mailx on ur machine

Answer (score 0):

Since [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) allows you access to the underlying interpreter, you can do a little Perl programming to add an END-Handler anywhere in your makefile:

```
perl { END { system "python send_email_when_done.py" }}
```

Or more prettily layouted with an alternate direct subject-only mail

```
perl {
  END {
    system "mail -s 'Build finished with rc=$?' me@my.home <&-";
  }
}
```

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things.*

Answer (score 0):

One way of obtaining that, would be to instruct make to ignore errors from the long-running programs. This can either be achieved by running `make -i` or by prepending each of the commands where failure should be ignored with a dash and just running plain `make`:

```
# Makefile
all: results1.dat results2.dat results3.dat
    python send_email_when_done.py

results1.dat: long_running_program1.py
    -python $< > $@ # this takes ~12 hours

results2.dat: long_running_program1.py results1.dat
    -python $^ > $@ # this takes ~2 hours 

results2.dat: long_running_program1.py results2.dat
    -python $^ > $@ # this takes ~30 hours
```

See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html) for more information on ignoring errors.